# Django allauth custom signup form error: 'Institution' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-allauth

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I'm getting the following error:

```
'Institution' object is not iterable
```

It doesn't like this line in the code:

```
user.institution = institution
```

Here's the full SignupForm class for Django allauth:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        label="Your First Name",
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        label="Your Last Name",
    )
    institution = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label="Your Institution",
        queryset=Institution.objects.all(),
        empty_label="Other Institution Not Listed",
    )

    def signup(self, request, user):
        from pprint import pprint
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.institution = self.cleaned_data['institution']

        user.save()
```

I've checked `self.cleaned_data` and it appears to be passing the institution correctly:

```
{'email': 'blah@blah',
 'first_name': 'John',
 'institution': <Institution: Blah College>,
 'last_name': 'Doe'}
```

I'm using a custom user model and institution is a many-to-many:

```
institution = models.ManyToManyField(Institution, db_index=True)
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a ManyToMany relationship then you need to use the `add` method to associate an institution with the user:

```
user.institution.add(self.cleaned_data['institution'])
```

You can read more about operations on Many-to-many relationships [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: Gah, there it is. Staring right at me in the face. Thank you!